# jquery Mobile : How to add an anchor to a panel

Tags: jquery, mobile, anchor, panel

I need to add some links (as images) on a Panel but can't seem to get it working.

Check http://jsfiddle.net/Ej7A7/418/

In the panel section there is the anchor:

`<a data-ajax=false href="javascript:alert('eee');return false;">Link does not work?</a>`

Open the panel (click on the Menu button).

On the panel there is the 'Link does not work?' .

Clicking on it should open an Alert box but it doesn't.

Anyone any ideas why ?

Comment: if opened an alert - am i missing something?

Comment: you have to click 'run' after making any changes btw

Comment: Hi, thx for the comments. I noticed that when I open the fiddle on my Mac/Safari the alert does not work, it does work on my PC using Chrome. As I was testing on my Mac I did not understand why this was not working (still don't understand). Not a Mac user either.